# What are the requirements for the "Ghost" experience bonus?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Lets say that I don't drag a knocked out enemy away, so that a patrol spots hims and starts searching for me. If I hide behind a wall where he is patrolling and is about to turn the corner, I can often get a quick take down on him, however he does say "Holy.." or "I heard..." just before so he has clearly spotted me.  The same goes if I run up to someone to take them out.

Does this mean that I am not eligible for the Ghost XP award and the achievement for:

> **Foxiest of the Hounds (100)**
>   Complete Deus Ex: Human Revolution without
>   setting off any alarms.

I bring up the Foxiest of the Hounds achievement, because when I make noise to try and lure someone out, the game switches to "Alarmed" status on my HUD.

**Edit:**

These game HUD states confuse me:

- Alarmed
- Suspicious
- Hostile

Am I correct in assuming that only the "Hostile" state means that I am no longer eligible for the Ghost.

Comment: The alarms in foxiest of all hounds only refers to actual alarms, i.e. ones that are triggered by security systems or when an enemy pushes the alarm panel.  Either way you are fine for that unless alarms really sound and all enemies go into permanent alerted state.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Added stuff to my answer below regarding the new part to your question. Also edited the title to reflect the question better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *does* mean that you aren't eligible for the `Ghost` experience bonus.

It *does not* mean that you aren't eligible for the `Foxiest of the Hounds` achievement.

Foxiest of the Hounds refers to if a guard runs up to an alarm panel and activates it, or a camera sets off an alarm, not the "alarmed" state that guards can go into.

Also, you already lost the "Ghost" bonus because someone spotted a body.

EDIT:

Alarmed occurs whenever a guard sees (or hears) something out of the ordinary. For example, a door open, a dead body, a hole in the wall that you punched out etc. This state varies. This state *WILL* disqualify you from receiving Ghost if someone spotted you or a body or something similar. This state *WILL NOT* disqualify you from receiving Ghost if someone spots a door opening, a hole in the wall or something similar. (At least I think this is how it works, I've received and not received Ghost in these ways, but I'm not 100% sure if this is exactly how it works)

Suspicious occurs whenever you're spotted by a camera or after guards have been hostile for a while and you've remained hidden for a while, they'll revert back to alarmed, and then suspicious. This state *WILL NOT* disqualify you from getting Ghost.

Hostile means that they're actively searching for your last seen location and occurs only if you've been spotted by a camera (for long enough) a robot or a guard. This state *WILL* disqualify you from getting Ghost.

Comment: Also, it is possible to do frontal takedowns without being spotted if you're hiding behind a wall and you take them down as they come around without them seeing you, sometimes you'll do a frontal takedown without them saying anything or them seeing you at all.

Comment: What does "spotted" actually mean. You HUD going into "Hostile" state? The same for alarms. What does "Suspicious" state mean?

Comment: @Layke - I can only recall "Suspicious" being used with security cameras, specifically, when you are in the camera's line of sight for a brief instant, but not long enough for them to turn red and start the alarm.

Comment: usually when I open a door and alert a guard, I use third party mode and hug the wall by the door and spam q.  As soon as they are in range, I do a takedown and they never enter the 'hostile' mode.  Works most of the time unless you are hiding behind some low object and they spot you before getting close enough.

Comment: I've read that if a turret spots you, unless he fired at you, you're still eligible for the "ghost" bonus, even though he instantly moves to the "Hostile" state. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: @idan Turrets, yes, robots, no. A turret has to fire at least one shot at you.

Comment: I don't think you lose ghost as soon as someone sees a body. That would make no sense for mines (it's possible to get ghost with mines) because everyone would see each other die and you'd lose ghost. You only lose ghost if they go hit the alarm after seeing a body.